# Set value of a js file properties from outside of it

Tags: javascript, node.js, class

I`m new to JS and apologize for asking a primary question!
We have this `first.js` file as a js class example with:

```
const {MakeRequest} = require("./Request");

let api;
let token;
let unique_token;

function chat(data, unique_token = null) {
    try {
        if (api != null && token != null) {
            return MakeRequest(token, api, data, unique_token)
        } else {
            return {
                "provider": {
                    "website": "https://example.com",
                    "source": "Example"
                },
                "status": true,
                "response": [],
                "options": {},
                "error": {
                    "code": 207,
                    "message": "Token or Api token did not valueted!"
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (e) {
        return {
            "provider": {
                "website": "https://example.com",
                "source": "Example"
            },
            "status": true,
            "response": [],
            "options": {},
            "error": {
                "code": e.code,
                "message": e.message
            }
        }
    }
}

module.exports = {
    token,api,unique_token,chat
}
```

also, I have this `second.js` file as a executable js file:

```
const object = require("./first.js")

object.token ="123456"
object.api ="123456"
object.token ="123456"
console.log(object.chat("hello"))
```

If I run the `second.js` file, the `api` variable is `undefined` and didn`t get the value from `second.js`, how can I resolve this problem without change the `second.js` codes!

Answer (score 1):

You can't edit a variable from a scope outside where it was declared.

Consider passing the values as arguments to `chat` function when you call it.